# HOW TO ADDED Added connection Database Postgresql

Tags: javascript, express

this is my App.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');


const  { Pool, Client } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool ({
  user: 'yudhistira',
  database: 'sds_system',
  password: 'Mydatabase2102',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432
});

// Test connected to Db

pool.connect( err => {
  if(err){
    console.log(err.message)
  } else {
    console.log('connected')
  }
})

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index')(pool);
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


module.exports = app;
```

I try to use a "pool" in index routes...with this :

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index')(pool);
```

but, I got some errors...
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')"...

how to fix this?